# Remove leaflet divIcon "dot" when icon size set to 0,0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, leaflet

I have the following:

```
var myLatLng = new L.LatLng(lat, lng);
var labelIcon = L.divIcon(
   {
        iconSize: [0, 0],
        html: "<div style='font-family:arial; margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; font-size:" + fontSize + "px;'>" + labelText + "</div>"
   });
var myMarker = L.marker(myLatLng, { icon: labelIcon, riseOnHover: false, draggable: true, ID: labelID });
```

when it appears on my map, I get the text to in the div to appear but then there is this little dot that results from the , i think, the icon having a size of 0,0. I have tried to set the opacity of the div but that does not affect the icon opacity. Is there a way to eliminate or make hide the "dot" that is left behind from the marker?

Comment: Please make a jsFiddle so we can help you better.

Comment: Look here: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

`iconSize` is not necessary for creating a `divIcon`. You can pass in a `className` instead and then set the size via CSS. Here's a link to Leaflet's documentation [detailing the options available.](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon-iconsize) Here's a code snippet. `labels` is just geoJSON that I created with [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0). I saved the geoJSON to a variable which I later iterate over and add to `map`, which is a Leaflet map.

```
var labels = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
      {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Juneau"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -134.42115783691406,
        58.30209338988363
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Fort Yukon"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -145.27410507202148,
        66.5648589947054
      ]
    }
  }
};

labels.features.forEach(function(feature) {
  return L.marker(
    [feature.geometry.coordinates[1], feature.geometry.coordinates[0]], {
    icon: L.divIcon({
      className: 'label',
      html: feature.properties.name
    })
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

Additionally, here's the CSS I used to style a map recently. You'll need to change the cursor to `inherit` so it doesn't change into a pointer. The `text-shadow` gives the text a light black outline to make the labels more visible on the map.

```
.label {
  font-family: 'IM Fell DW Pica', serif;
  color: #fec623;
  font-size: 150%;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  cursor: inherit;
}
```